# Could a society with medieval technology discover all the planets in the solar system?

Tags: technology, technological-development, telescope

Could you have a telescope advanced enough to see a planet as far away as Neptune is from Earth, in a civilization with a tech level equivalent to 1100 AD? Would it be possible to discover all the planets in the solar system?

Just assume the furthest planet is Neptune, in terms of size, distance, and visibility.
On top of that, I have humans living on a moon of a gas giant. Since the beginning of time, they've looked up to see this massive object that dwarfs the sun, so society might be more inclined to focus on the skies. Maybe there's a greater push for studying astronomy. I don't know if that would be enough.

Comment: It is probable that _we_ haven’t yet discovered all the planets in the solar system with our current technology (it’s certain if you include dwarf planets). So you definitely couldn’t do it with a much lower tech level.

Comment: How does that moon’s atmosphere differ from Earth’s?

Comment: Neptune was discovered in 1846 (using math to imply its existence from its effect on the orbit of Uranus), so what technology that either didn't actually exist or could easily have existed (divorced from other advances) a little earlier than it did in our medieval world do you think is needed?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_discovery_of_Solar_System_planets_and_their_moons

Comment: Living on a moon orbiting a gas giant seems pretty different from living on a planet. Is it possible that your species might be slightly different from humans (better night vision, for example? Their day night cycle will be a little weird after all.). Also, what's the significance of the distance to Neptune in your story? There's a planet that is the farthest away one they can see, which they probably can't get to--how will your story change if it is 1 Jupiter-distance away? Maybe they move half as fast as us, so they think of the distance as twice as far away, hahaha.

Comment: I wouldn't say "Discovery" but i know that at least in ancient china their tech was advanced enough that they knew planets outside of our own existed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Neptune is invisible without a telescope**

Wikipedia states that Neptune's apparent magnitude is 7.3 to 8.0, while a naked eye with zero light pollution can detect stars of 6.0 magnitude or below. Therefore, the discovery of Neptune is not possible without a telescope.

**Uranus might be discovered to be a planet, but is too indiscernible to worry for low-tech people**

Uranus' magnitude is 5.3 to 6.0 as viewed from Earth, and it was probably even depicted as a star by Hipparchus in 128BC, so it *could* be discovered. Proving that it's not a star but a planet would require years of continuous observation, however, and it's too small to actually be watched over for years. Should someone really want to watch over Uranus, correctly identifying it in the sky full of other, brighter stars, they might conclude that it is indeed a planet, and not a moving star like Barnard's (almost said Baranar's XD). Checking and calculating its orbit would require dozens of years and enough mathematics to saturate a medieval society, yet it could technically be done.

As for the instrumental base, there was a fine gem of an astronomic device in the [Ulugh Beg Observatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulugh_Beg_Observatory), namely a great sextant with a radius of 40 meters, hidden deep in the rock and oriented so that an astronomer could technically watch over a single star in a wide enough region of the sky. While that observatory was built in the 1420s, the exact technological base is not so far from the 1100s in the question, and it also might quite possibly (or plausibly) be built in 1100s, perhaps downscaled at first, by your eager-to-learn-stars civilization.

**Telescopes require technology beyond what was known in the 1100s**

But the limiting tech is not optics, as research was done earlier, while not being systematic, but instead glass-making and creating fine parabolic and elliptic surfaces with sub-millimeter precision. Early lenses were known as early as the late Egyptian dynasties, or several hundred years BC. It's safe to assume that there were simple lenses still earlier, and basic laws of optics were described at about the same time in Greece, further refined by Ibn al-Haytham in the 11th century AD.  That said, making fine lenses that won't distort the image of a speckle at infinite range was not possible until the invention of precise machinery. This machinery required a set of technologies that only emerged with a scientific approach to mechanisms and the actual onset of the scientific renaissance.

You can potentially circumvent this timescale requirement by declaring that your civilization did not suffer the Dark Ages of religion suppressing scientific thought, so some of the dates could be shifted earlier, including requirement of public education to be able to provide more talents in any scientific field. Then your civ's 1100 could probably include a prototype of a spyglass, for example, which could eventually be turned towards the sky and find that there are more stars than are visible by the naked eye, with the subsequential rise of astronomy.

In summary: You are not able to have a telescope by 1100 in your civ *if* it develops according to our own timescale, so they can't discover Neptune. You *can* have devices built with 1100 AD tech that can help in detecting that Uranus is not a star, but there are difficulties in finding Uranus first, and watching over it for long enough to find out it's moving.

Comment: That makes sense. My world is only medieval in terms of technology. It's definitely not in a dark age for science. Religion is far less stringent. Given the alternate social structure, it might make sense that development happened sooner.
Either way, thanks for your answer. It was exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: Neptune was derived from orbital mechanics deviation calculations of uranus. You can compute those, if you build models, that behave similar to the equations you want to solve. Its the data basis for discovery that is important, the tools are just the final mile. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_computing

Comment: The "Dark Ages" were only dark in Europe.  The same time period is also known as the Golden Age of Islam, with impressive work in astronomy and mathematics.

Comment: @Mark yet telescopes first appeared in Europe in 1600s. I assume that the Islamic part of the world has also suffered somehow from their own dark ages, otherwise they should have been the discoverers of many things (yup Ibn Sina and Ibn al-Haytham, but they are single people, not a sizable group, compare Kulibin). Why didn't they? I don't exactly know.

Comment: @Pica this means the civ in question should have first discovered Uranus, then discover it's moving, *then* discover it's moving not exactly to the predictions. This requires observation tools with enough precision to find this discrepancy, so you're basically wrong here.

Comment: @Mark Thats a orientalist view. Most historians no longer subscribe to the "golden times" correlated with colonialist, expansive imperialism phase of empires history. piling up missery for small  inpermanent pockets of scholarship is not a bloom of wisdom.

Comment: @Vesper: It needs some precise observation, but mostly precise computation. Which could be done by a physical computer

Comment: @Pica if your gathered data is imprecise, or measurement error can't be made less than actual discrepancy, precise computation would not help. And increasing data precision requires better measurement tools.

Comment: @Pica it took a while to find how big was the error of observation of Uranus to expect another planet beyond it, the question is here https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/ which states the error was in order of tens of arcseconds per tens of years. Speaking of 1100s tools, the Ulug Beg sextant had angular precision at about 5 arcseconds/mm; considering that it was a 1400 building, a 1100 one should have worse precision. I'm not sure whether actual observation precision is limited by the atmosphere at lower values (it well might be), and voila, we are already at the error margin.

Comment: @Vesper :.( You are right. Although, if you have a model, like a orbital one, deviations accumulate up. So even with inprecise observation, the deviation becomes noticeable over long time intervalls.

Comment: Why does this often-debunked myth of *"Dark Ages of religion suppressing scientific thought"* come up again and again? There is absolutely no evidence of any systematic religious suppression of technological inventions during the so-called "dark ages" in Europe. In fact there was a slow but steady technological advancement throughout the era, and it is called dark because there are fewer written sources from that era than from preceding and succeeding eras. That whole myth of "technology was banned by religion" is a 19th century re-imagination of history.

Comment: @vsz it could be that we want to believe our civilization is intellectually and morally superior, which needs a point of comparison. Previously that would have been with civilizations that were geographically distant, now we use ones that are temporally distant.

Answer (score 5):

**Depends on Definitions.**

The *identification* of Neptune as a planet rather than a distant star required telescopes, mathematics, and timekeeping. Together, those allowed observers to spot a movement which did not follow the pattern of a [fixed star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_stars).

If they can make a telescope like that, are they still medieval or have they advanced beyond it? If they can calculate orbits like that, are they still medieval or have they advanced beyond it? TV Tropes speaks of [Bamboo Technology](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BambooTechnology) when a setting ignores this.

I would say you can have a society which looks and feels medieval and detects Neptune, but if you poke at the details, you might find scientists investigating the trajectory of a cannon ball (or a catapult stone) with decidedly non-medieval means.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in a world where you have humans (or carbon-base lifeforms) on an Earth-like planet orbiting a gas giant then you're obviously not in the solar system.

So posit that your system's star is much more luminous than our sun.  Assuming that the gas giant is still in the habitable zone of its star, it will still need to receive roughly the same amount of energy from the star (i.e., the perceived brightness of the star from the planet's surface will be the same as the perceived brightness of the Sun on Earth.)  Your planet will need to have a greater orbital radius around its star.

But this means that a Neptune-like planet a given distance away from the Earth-like planet will actually be *brighter* than Neptune is in our Solar System.  The reason Neptune is so dim (even at its brightest) is that the sunlight has to travel 1 AU to get to us but a further 58 AU to get to Neptune and back to us (29 AU each way).  If we assume that the Neptune-like planet is still 29 AU farther out, but the Earth-like planet is 2 AU or 3 AU away from its parent star, the fractional difference between the direct path and the round-trip path becomes smaller;  which means that the Neptune-like planet would end up being brighter.

Some more detailed calculations yield the graph below.  (Remember, lower apparent magnitude means brighter, because astronomers are weird.)
[image]

- A habitable planet orbiting its star at 2 AU (with "Neptune" at 31 AU) would see "Neptune" to have a peak magnitude of about 5.8.  This would be visible in dark skies at closest approach, but it's straining the limits of visibility.  It would be too dim to see visible when it's at other points in its orbit — but this would include times when it would only be above the horizon during the daytime anyhow.
- If the planet orbited its planet at 3 AU, with "Neptune" at 32 AU, its magnitude would vary between about 5.0 and 6.0.  This would be pretty comparable to Uranus in our current solar system, which [(as noted by vesper)](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/256435/15809) would be observable in principle but would present the same sorts of difficulties.

The downside of this is that these stars, being brighter, would also be shorter-lived.  Whether or not there would be enough time for your creatures to evolve on such a world is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

The Galilean moons of Jupiter have apparent magnitudes between 4.6 and 5.6 when Jupiter is in opposition to the sun. The dimmer ones are about as bright as Uranus. They would be easily visible as stars if they were not 10 arc minutes from Jupiter, which is almost a thousand times brighter. The people who see them without telescopes often use some distant ground-based object such as a tree-trunk to block off Jupiter.

If someone thought to look for moons around Jupiter, then people could have seen them in medieval times. They were bright enough to see, and very close to a bright object, so they can be located. The move relative to Jupiter, so they would have been interesting. I find it quite possible that Hipparchus may have seen Uranus, and marked it down as a star, but there are thousands of stars with a similar magnitude, and it would be hard to tell it moved without some point of reference.

IMHO, people could have seen the moons of Jupiter in medieval times, but no-one did. This suggests the much less noticeable points of light that were Uranus and Neptune would not be recognized as planets.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly clear that the society could have discovered all the planets in medieval times. Certainly lenses were good enough around that time and had been for hundreds of years (as some of the other excellent answers state, thankyou @Vesper).

The thing is that there must be an incentive to do it. What would drive a civilisation which is largely still undeveloped in terms of farming, machinery and agriculture to *want* to do this? Everything is such effort. What is required is an elite group of highly rich people who have made great finances and live in luxury somehow, who will pay for the development and study of the stars. This might be for religious reasons or just because a rich family is interested and bored.

Boredom is the perfect environment for creativity. People who have to spend every waking moment trying to forage for all they need to survive are not bored neither will they show much interest in vesting any of their precious time into trying to figure out what is in the sky (unless there's a survival reason, which for a society like that usually comes down to some sort of religion).

So yes, the technology is there. But you have to ensure that the society allows it. Which means that you have to have a big enough government such that unlike in the UK in the medieval times with so many kings smashing each other's castles up all the time, they can actually have some space and stability to be bored and do leisure activities, including researching things that can have no bearing on their future. (unless it's for religious reasons).

The other thing might be that instead of religious discovery, it might be the case that they can actually get into space. This is not unusual; in cases where there is excessive government control the government can exist in lavish highly advanced compounds whereas everybody else is foraging to survive and has done for generations with no knowledge of the luxuries of the government. In that case, a story where the guys outside of the government end up realising that to survive and thrive they need to know where the planets in the sky are (I'm not going to try and write your story for you) would result in that tech being developed effectively in a medieval environment.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial observation: it is impossible to do something unless you try. IMHO medieval people wouldn't have tried to find all the planets because they thought they already knew them all.

If you read Dante's Commedia, Paradiso assumes the canonical 5 planets, plus Sun and the Moon. There are 9 spheres, for the Moon, Sun, planets, fixed stars, and the Primum Mobile, and sphere are mapped onto various theological concepts: there wasn't room for more planets. Moreover, Dante's theology was orthodox. People didn't look for more planets, because they has no reason to believe there were any.

Others have already mentioned Uranus and Neptune. Herschel wasn't looking for new planets; he was as surprised as anyone to find one. Neptune is the first instance of a planet being discovered by people who were looking for a new one.